# Values of $d$ in a congruence problem $dp \equiv s \mod N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm solving an algorithm problem and it boils down to solving  the congruency $$dp \equiv s \mod N$$
for the smalest value of $d$. Is there a way I can use number theory to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your congruence will have a solution if and only if $\gcd(p,\ N)=g| s$ and there will be $g$ solutions modulo $N$.

The general solution is given by the extended Euclidean algorithm. See the [linear congruence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem) and the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) which outlines a method of solution.